# What's the name of the new Roleplaying in Glorantha game?

Tags: product-identification, runequest, runequest-glorantha

RuneQuest has (for me) a winding path of editions and publishers, at least in comparison with other rpgs. Adding the Glorantha setting to the mix doesn't make it easier.

The last RuneQuest from **The Design Mechanism** was RuneQuest 6th edition, and, as far as I know, according to **Chaosium**, this iteration follows RuneQuest 3rd. Also, I've read about as *RuneQuest* and as *Roleplaying in Glorantha*, and RiG is an acronym I've seen around, but it doesn't tell me anything about the edition!

So, is this RuneQuest 7th edition? 3rd edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copyright page says:

> RUNEQUEST
>   A Chaosium Game
>   First Chaosium Edition 1978
>   Second Chaosium Edition 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983
>   Third Chaosium/Avalon Hill Edition 1984, 1993
>   Fourth Chaosium Edition 2018
>   Copyright ©1978, 1980, 1984, 1993, 2018 by Moon Design Publications, all rights reserved.
>   RuneQuest, HeroQuest, and Glorantha are trademarks of Moon Design Publications.

So it is "Fourth Edition."

Comment: Now I wrote "3rd edition?" on the question when it should have been 4th.

Anyway, that's what Chaosium says now. What about MGP RQ's and TDM's 6e? Does it mean we're having non-linear numbering editions? Have they stated that the editions following AH's one are not "canon"?

Comment: @Cazacurdas: I don't know the answers to your questions. The Mongoose RuneQuest had significant mechanical differences from the Chaosium BRP system, clearly inspired by D&D3e, and I suspect the Moon Design people would not have wanted to include them. "Canon" isn't really a meaningful concept for Glorantha: it's too mythic for that.